# is it possible to add meta FAQs to webpages that are parsed by search engines

Tags: seo, meta-description

For a single webpage is it possible to add questions and answers complementing the webpage content.
I am talking about non-visible (meta) content that will just help in SEO.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, **no it is not possible** without violating Google's guidelines.

According to [Google's structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies):

> **Don't** mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page.

So adding extra FAQs to structured data, if they are not visible on the page, is a violation and is likely to get your structured data ignored.

I imagine that other search engines probably have similar policies.